# What does this bit of papyrus say?

Tags: greek, text-corpus, papyrology, sappho

Below is a bit of P.Oxy.2076. Full image of that papyrus [here](http://163.1.169.40/gsdl/collect/POxy/index/assoc/HASH011f/ee301502.dir/POxy.v0017.n2076.a.01.hires.jpg).

[image: Papyrus.]

I read it as:

> ϹΑΠΦΟ[
>                Β
>   ΜΙΤ̣I̤ΝΥΔΥ[

The first two lines read `Σαπφο[ῦς] Β`, i.e. "Sappho [book] 2", but the third line? What could that be saying?

**Note**

I just realized I hadn't written that, in the above transcription, I distinguish between a single underdot (like under the T), which means a somewhat doubtful letter, and a double underdot (like under the I), which means a letter so doubtful that the given suggestion is just a guess, because e.g. it is only partially present and the rest could lead to many different letters.

Comment: [Here](http://163.1.169.40/gsdl/collect/POxy/index/assoc/HASH011f/ee301502.dir/POxy.v0017.n2076.a.01.hires.jpg) is the full scrap.

Comment: William Johnson (Johnson 2004, *Bookrolls and scribes in Oxyrhynchus*) refers to the scribe who added these marginal scholia as scribe A6 (late 1st or early 2nd century AD). Other papyri by the same scribe - 1809 and 2288. In any case, this is irrelevant to the task of translating Sappho.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Lobel-Page (p. 37) give `.[.......] γὰρ ἐφίλει δυ[`, saying, "Sub coloph. **2076** schol. vestigia...quod quorsum spectet obscurum est." I'm not trained in papyrology (I much prefer inscriptions—far easier to read!), so it's difficult for me to judge, at least without seeing the papyrus in person.